# how to properly setup laravel with bootstrap 4 (sass)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a doubt relative to what is the correct way to use bootstrap 4 with sass and laravel? Its equal just donwload the source files and put them in the public folder or it is better use npm?

And for each case what is the properly process to configure the bootstrap with laravel?

For the case of just download the source files we can create for example a bootstrap folder inside /public/css/ and paste there the sass files that are in the source files folder? But then how to import the css in the html file?

And for the case of using npm, do you know some tutorial that works? It appears there are many ways but there is some recommended process for this that works? I use the command on the project folder `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2` then change in bootstrap.js "bootstrap-sass" to "bootstrap" then in app.scss I change the 3rd import to "`@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap`". I dont know if this process is correct, but if it is, now to edit the layout, the bootstrap css files we should do that in the bootstrap folder inside node_modules? Or we should copy that bootstrap folder to the public folder or something?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it

First, get rid of what you won't use anymore

`yarn remove bootstrap-sass`

Then install what you WILL need

`yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 popper.js`

Now open **resources/assets/bootstrap.js** (nothing to do with the Bootstrap we're talking about)

Look for

```
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Substitute it for

```
window.Popper = require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

Then go to **resources/assets/sass/app.scss**

Look for

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

And substitute it for

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
```

That's it!

You should be able to run `yarn run dev` or `yarn run watch` and see changes taking effect.